# biglm finds the wrong data.frame to take the data from

Tags: r, assign, lm, chunks, chunking

I am trying to create chunks of my dataset to run `biglm`. (with fastLm I would need 350Gb of RAM)

My complete dataset is called `res`. As experiment I drastically decreased the size to 10.000 rows. I want to create chunks to use with biglm.

```
library(biglm)

formula <- iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Sepal.Width

test <- iris[1:10,]

biglm(formula, test)
```

And somehow, I get the following output:

```
> test <- iris[1:10,]
> test
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
```

Above you can see the matrix `test` contains 10 rows. Yet when running `biglm` it shows a sample size of 150

```
> biglm(formula, test)
Large data regression model: biglm(formula, test)
Sample size =  150
```

Looks like it uses `iris` instead of `test`.. how is this possible and how do I get biglm to use chunk1 the way I intend it to?

Comment: I updated the code to a reproducable sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the following line is to blame:

```
formula <- iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Sepal.Width
```

where in the formula you explicitly reference the `iris` dataset. This will cause R to try and find the `iris` dataset when `lm` is called, which it finds in the global environment (because of R's scoping rules).

In a formula you normally do not use vectors, but simply the column names:

```
formula <- Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width
```

This will ensure that the formula contains only the column (or variable) names, which will be found in the data `lm` is passed. So, `lm` will use `test` in stead of `iris`.

Comment: Thanks heaps! can't believe how long I was stuck on this today!